# Is there a list of well-known network service names?

Tags: networking, service, network-programming

The Android developer documentation for NsdManager.discoverServices() says the argument 'String serviceType' is "The service type being discovered. Examples include "_http._tcp" for http services or "_ipp._tcp" for printers". Is there a list of such known service type strings? How would a developer learn of the other strings not given in the example?

I have found documentation on the known TCP port numbers, and I suspect that there are strings associated with most of the well-known ports. Where is that list?

(I allude here to the Android network API, but the question is not specific to Android, the answer will not be in the Android domain)

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the services are defined for a standard called [DNS-SRV](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2782.txt). The official list of services is managed by IANA. You can find a list [here](https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/).